# Docker container stopped working and deleted all files

Tags: docker, docker-container

When I was training my model (using Jupiter notebook), I got the message in Jupyter like "Kernel died...". when tried to restore everything, it didn't work. Then I decided to restart my container, however, I got the following message:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"jupyter\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Error: failed to start containers: silly_bose
```

After that, I started to look at my container's data from the host and I realized that all my files are gone.

[image]

Can anyone help me please until I got a heart attack?
Is that possible that docker may delete files on its own?

Comment: did you mount the host path with your container? `"exec: \"jupyter\": executable file not found in $PATH":` are mounting the correct path?

Comment: yes it's mounted